# Can't call function in unit test from integration test code?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

There is a code commonly used in unit test and integration test. In order to expose the function on the unit test, the pub keyword is added to the module and function. However, the following error occurs when the function is called in the integration test.

### Error

```
>> cargo test tls_get_with_no_body
   
error[E0433]: failed to resolve: could not find `tests` in `register`
  --> tests/server.rs:28:34
   |
28 |             .json_body(register::tests::get_sample_register_response_body());
   |                                  ^^^^^ could not find `tests` in `register`
```

My file structure is roughly as follows:

```
 engine
     ├── src
     │   ├── admin
     │   │   ├── register.rs // contains unit test
     ├── tests
     │   ├── server.rs // for integration test
```

And test code is below.

```
/src/admin/register.rs (unit test)

...
#[cfg(test)]
pub mod tests {
    use super::*;
    use httpmock::prelude::*;

    ...
     #[tokio::test(flavor = "multi_thread")]
    async fn register_success() {
        let mock_server = MockServer::start();
        let m = mock_server.mock(|when, then| {
            when.path("/register")
                .header("content-type", "application/json")
                .header_exists("content-type")
                .json_body_partial(
                    r#"
                    {  
                        "engineName": "engine_for_mock"
                    }
                    "#,
                );
            then.status(200)
                .header("content-type", "application/json")
                .json_body(get_sample_register_response_body());
        });
        ....
        assert_eq!(result.unwrap().id, "123b78dd5b504a32ad5f0456");
    }

    pub fn get_sample_register_response_body() -> serde_json::Value {
        let sample = serde_json::json!(
            {
                "id": "123b78dd5b504a32ad5f0456",
                "config":
                {   "threads":"CPU * 2",
                    "listenHttpPort":"5582",
                        "listenHttps":
                        {   "port":"",
                            "certificateFileName":"",
                            "certificateFileData":"",
                            "privateKeyFileName":"",
                            "privateKeyFileData":"",
                            "password":"",
                            "_id":"61c200c329d74b196d48c2a3"
                        },
                    "accessLogFormat":"%h %t \"%r\" %s %b %D %{X-Forwarded-For}i",
                    "systemLogLevel":"Info",
                    "_id":"61c200c329d74b196d48c2a2"
                }
            }
        );
        sample
    }
}
```

Same use `get_sample_register response_body()` in integration test.

```
/tests/server.rs(integration test)

use engine::admin::{poll, register};
...
#[tokio::test(flavor = "multi_thread")]
async fn tls_get_with_no_body() {
  ...
    let admin_server = MockServer::start();
    let register_mock = admin_server.mock(|when, then| {
            when.path("/register");
            then.status(200)
                .header("content-type", "application/json")
                .json_body(register::tests::get_sample_register_response_body());// error
    });

}
```

When writing code, the IDE does not generate an error and finds the path well. But when I run the test, an error occurs. Can't the test module be made public?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cfg(test)` is only enabled when *tests in the current crate* are being compiled. "Integration" tests in `tests/` are separate crates, so when run, they use your library compiled *normally*, without the special `test` configuration.

Roughly speaking, `#[cfg(test)]` is only useful to `#[test]` tests in the same crate. In every other case, items with `#[cfg(test)]` will not be compiled.